# How do these active/passive ports differ from each other?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3B+ to automate a Peristaltic pump with Python.

The pump has an external interface on it and the manual provides detailed description of it. (Attached)

Now the issue is; every function has two ports available for it. Passive and Active. My question is, how do these two differ? Which one should I be using?

Thank you.

[image: External Control Interface Description in the manual]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about electronic components and not related to software development.

Comment: Agree with @KlausD. on this one but maybe this is helpful? https://blog.wika.com/products/pressure-products/active-passive-sensor/

Not really my specialty, but the pages from the manual are not very specific, there might be something more there if you keep reading?

Comment: @KlausD. along with voting as off-topic, would you please point me in the direction of the right forum to ask this kind of questions? That'd be much appreciated.